# como criar índice order desc através do DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, dataannotations

Preciso criar um índice em minha model, porém preciso que ela seja decrescente

Como estou fazendo:

```
[Index("Ix_PrecoConsultData", IsUnique = false, Order = 1)]
public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
```

Ela cria o índice porém com ordem ASC preciso que esse índice seja DESC
Pelo visto esse Order é para caso tenha mais de uma coluna no índice.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão, não existe nada para fazer o que deseja. Porém, nada impede que você faça o seu **Custom Migrations Generator**, como mostrado [nesta resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615040/4843158)

Para isso, basta criar uma classe herdando de [SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.sql.sqlservermigrationsqlgenerator(v=vs.103).aspx) e realizar a configuração deseja (não somente para índex).

Par ao nosso exemplo, faremos o seguinte:

```
public class CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation)
    {
        using (var writer = Writer())
        {
            writer.Write("CREATE ");

            if (createIndexOperation.IsUnique)
            {
                writer.Write("UNIQUE ");
            }

            if (createIndexOperation.IsClustered)
            {
                writer.Write("CLUSTERED ");
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write("NONCLUSTERED ");
            }

            string name = createIndexOperation.Name;
            string[] sorts = {};
            if (createIndexOperation.Name.Contains(":"))
            {
                var parts = createIndexOperation.Name.Split(':');

                if (parts.Length >= 1)
                {
                    name = parts[0];
                }
                if (parts.Length >= 2)
                {
                    sorts = parts[1].Split(',');
                }
            }

            writer.Write("INDEX ");
            writer.Write(Quote(name));
            writer.Write(" ON ");
            writer.Write(Name(createIndexOperation.Table));
            writer.Write("(");

            // Add the columns to the index with their respective sort order
            string fields = "";
            if (sorts.Length == 0 || sorts.Length == createIndexOperation.Columns.Count)
            {
                for (int i=0 ; i<createIndexOperation.Columns.Count ; i++)
                {
                    string sort = "ASC";
                    if (sorts.Length == 0)
                    {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                    else if (sorts[i] != "ASC" && sorts[i] != "DESC")
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Expected sort for {0} is 'ASC' or 'DESC. Received: {1}", name, sorts[i]));
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        sort = sorts[i];  
                    }

                    fields = fields + Quote(createIndexOperation.Columns[i]) + " " + sort + ",";
                }
                fields = fields.Substring(0, fields.Length - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("The sort (ASC/DEC) count is not equal to the number of fields in your Index ({0}).", name));
            }

            writer.Write(fields);

            writer.Write(")");
            Statement(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Feito isso, basta adicionar a referência em seu `Configuration.cs`, desta forma:

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());

    }
```

Agora, basta decorar o seu atributo com o final `:DESC` ou `:ASC`, conforme desejado. Ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
[Index("Ix_PrecoConsultData:DESC", IsUnique = false, Order = 1)]
public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
```

E isso gerará o seguinte `SQL`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DATA] ON [dbo].[TABLENAME]([DataCadastro] DESC)
```

Caso queira mais explicações, [este artigo](https://romiller.com/2012/01/16/customizing-code-first-migrations-provider/) possui a mesma implementação, mas de forma diferente, utilizando `anonymousArguments{}` nas migrations.

Caso não goste desta solução, você também pode criar o SQL na mão e adicionar à migration gerada, desta forma:

```
namespace Wmb.Mmn.Common.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class teste : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            //Migration Gerada
            //CreateIndex("dbo.Categorias", "DataCriacao", name: "IX_DATA");

            //SQL Index
            Sql("CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DATA] ON [dbo].[Categorias]([DataCriacao] DESC)");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropIndex("dbo.Categorias", "IX_DATA");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a primeira solução achei uma bala de canhão pra matar minha formiga..rs Acho que vou com a 2ª opção, mas é bom saber da 1ª resposta mesmo assim.